# What are outgoing messages in Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I need help interpreting this graph:
[image]
It looks like messages are coming in, then being processed, and going back to 0. The graph is not continually rising.

However, the outgoing messages has "--". Does this mean 0?

**Does an outgoing message represent a message being read by a service?**

If the messages are not being read, then what is happening to them? The dead letter queue has 0 messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an outgoing message represents a message being read by a service.

In your case, I see you've `disabled` the dead letter queue(in your screenshot, the `Dead lettering` option is disabled.), so there is no messages in the DLQ. If DLQ is disabled, the messages will get deleted after they expire.

Answer (score 4):

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor#message-metrics) describes them like this:

> The number of events or messages received from Service Bus over a specified period.

So, the incoming messages are message that are sent to the service bus. The outgoing messages are messages that are picked up by message processors (your application). So the answer to your question

> Does an outgoing message represent a message being read by a service?

is: Yes!